# Importing .pdf image created by Inkscape UNSCALED

Tags: pdf, scaling, inkscape

I created a simple drawing in Inkscape, which I exported as .pdf to include it into a LaTeX file.

In the image I want to have a nice 5mm grid. (Created using Extensions->Render->Grids...)

If I print the so exported pdf file out, it get a perfect 5mm grid on paper.

Before exporting in Inkscape, I defined the page size to be 13cmx13cm. 
(Using document properties).
In the exporting to pdf process, I check the box 'Export area is page'.

If I include it in LaTeX like this:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics{one.pdf}
\rule{35em}{0.8pt}
\caption{Werkst"uck von Aufgabe \ref{q:1}}
\label{fig:one}
\end{figure}
```

my LaTeX compiler creates my a pdf in which the image is TOO SMALL. 
Meaning I do not get my nice 5 mm grid.

In fact I have to scale the image up like this:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.068]{one.pdf}
\rule{35em}{0.8pt}
\caption{Werkst"uck von Aufgabe \ref{q:1}}
\label{fig:one}
\end{figure}
```

in order to get my desired 5 mm Grid an the Drawing / Image in 
original size, which is all I want.

(I am using:
pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2014.9.22) )

What could be the cause?

Comment: Are you choosing to export only the draw on Inkscape or are you exporting the whole page?

Comment: In addition, when you printed the PDF to check the grid spacing, did you have all page-scaling features of the printer driver turned off?

Comment: page-scaling features, I used: 'Page scaling: Shrink to printable area'.

Comment: @eric, this is not a good idea. Print it in 100% original size.

Comment: @Sigur Good question: Check above, I edited the original question.

Comment: @eric if you allowed the printer driver to do arbitrary scaling, how do you know the grid is actually 5 mm?

Comment: Open the pdf file with pdf viewer and check its properties to see if the media size is in fact 13x13.

Comment: @Sigur, I also noticed something odd:
As I specified the page size (13x13cm) and exported it accordingly (option 'export area is page' set), 
the printer printed more than it should have.
Meaning that it printed beyond the specified limit.

Comment: @Sigur. I opened the pdf file properties, and the page size check out correct!

Comment: Try to edit your draw and make sure that the grid is simply curves, no groups or other kinds of objects.

Comment: @PaulGessler Indeed, that makes sens, forgive me, I will do it again tomorrow morning

Comment: @Sigur Indeed, I have the grid on a separate layer underneath the "actual" drawing. I also suspected that might cause problems? But it shouldn't right? :-)

Comment: I'm trying to create a grid. After changed the page dimensions, the grid don't appear aligned with the borders. It appears outside the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20591/discussion-between-eric-and-sigur).

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just draw the grid rather than doing it in Inkscape and then exporting it and then including it?

Comment: @cfr Indeed, but I need the grid perfectly aligned with the drawing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an issue with printer settings and external graphics creation, not (La)TeX.

Comment: Or maybe I should delete the whole thing? 
(honestly, I did just something stupid)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: It was a printing error:

Here is the fix:
Under Ubuntu 14.04 (Linux), if you have the final pdf which latex creates for you;
If you print it, after you press Crtl. + P, you have to:
Page handling -> page scaling -> NO SCALING